# loop over variable names

Tags: r, function, loops, regression

I am trying to build various regression models with different columns (independent variables in my dataset).

```
set.seed(0)
True = rnorm(20, 100, 10)
v = matrix(rnorm(120, 10, 3), nrow = 20)
dt = data.frame(cbind(True, v))
colnames(dt) = c('True', paste0('ABC', 1:6))
```

So the independent variables I want to throw in the data is "ABCi", aka when i=1, use ABC1, etc. Each model uses the first 80% of the observations to build, then I make a prediction on the rest 20%.

I tried this:

```
reg.pred = rep(0, ncol(dt))
for (i in 1:nrow(dt)){
  reg = lm(True~paste0('ABC', i), data = dt[(1:(0.8*nrow(dt))),])
  reg.pred[i] = predict(reg, data = dt[(0.8*nrow(dt)):nrow(dt),])
}
```

Not working... giving errors like:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = True ~ paste0("ABC", i), data = dt[(1:(0.8 *  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'paste0("ABC", i)')
```

Not sure how can I retrieve the variable name in a loop... Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you're looping through rows with `for (i in 1:nrow(dt)){` instead of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not technically need to use `as.formula()` as @Sonny suggests, but you cannot mix a character representation of the formula and formula notation. So, you need to fix that. However, once you do, you'll notice that there are other issues with your code that @Sonny either did not notice or opted not to address.

Most notably, the line

```r
reg.pred = rep(0, ncol(dt))
```

implies you want a single prediction from each model, but

```
predict(reg, data = dt[(0.8*nrow(dt)):nrow(dt),])
```

implies you want a prediction for each of the observations not in the training set (you'll need a +1 after `0.8*nrow(dt)` for that by the way).

I think the following should fix all your issues:

```
set.seed(0)
True = rnorm(20, 100, 10)
v = matrix(rnorm(120, 10, 3), nrow = 20)
dt = data.frame(cbind(True, v))
colnames(dt) = c('True', paste0('ABC', 1:6))
# Make a matrix for the predicted values; each column is for a model
reg.pred = matrix(0, nrow = 0.2*nrow(dt), ncol = ncol(dt)-1)
for (i in 1:(ncol(dt)-1)){
    # Get the name of the predictor we want here
    this_predictor <- paste0("ABC", i)
    # Make a character representation of the lm formula
    lm_formula <- paste("True", this_predictor, sep = "~")
    # Run the model
    reg = lm(lm_formula, data = dt[(1:(0.8*nrow(dt))),])
    # Get the appropriate test data
    newdata <- data.frame(dt[(0.8*nrow(dt)+1):nrow(dt), this_predictor])
    names(newdata) <- this_predictor
    # Store predictions
    reg.pred[ , i] = predict(reg, newdata = newdata)
}

reg.pred

#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]      [,4]      [,5]     [,6]
# [1,] 100.2150 100.8394 100.7915  99.88836  97.89952 105.7201
# [2,] 101.2107 100.8937 100.9110 103.52487 102.13965 104.6283
# [3,] 100.0426 101.0345 101.2740 100.95785 102.60346 104.2823
# [4,] 101.1055 100.9686 101.5142 102.56364 101.56400 104.4447
```

In this matrix of predictions, each column is from a different model, and the rows correspond to the last four rows of your data (the rows not in your training set).

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, I didn't realize the errors in my original code, and now it works perfectly. Really appreciated!

Comment: @RachelZhang Great, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `as.formula`

```
  f <- as.formula(
    paste("True", 
          paste0('ABC', i), 
          sep = " ~ "))

  reg = lm(f, data = dt[(1:(0.8*nrow(dt))),])
```

Comment: Did you try running her code with that modification?